# Primefaces Bar Chart -- Hide X-Axis label?

Tags: jsf, graph, primefaces, charts

I'm using Primefaces' bar chart component to print data over a period of 30 days.  The problem is, there are so many points on the chart that the x-axis labels overlap and are unreadable.  For our purposes, these labels are not important.  How can I hide these values so they are not displayed at all?  I've tried some of the jqPlot options, but I appear to be doing it wrong.  Setting them ends up distorting my graph.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try This one it's Working. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612972/10150796

Answer (score 0):

did you tried by tilting your label using "angle". so it will be inclined position, where it wont merge with others.

```
var AxisAngle = "-30";
this.cfg.axes = {
        yaxis : {           
            tickOptions : {         
                angle : AxisAngle
            }
        },
        xaxis : {           
            tickOptions : {         
                angle : AxisAngle
            }
        }
    };
```