# coca pod Chart not appearing (Swift4)

Tags: ios, charts, cocoapods, swift4

My chart is not displaying any bars using this bar graph. I have successfully imported the charts cocoa pod. There are currently no run time errors. The only thing that is being displayed in the graph is the description label.

```
    import UIKit
import Charts
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var lineChartVIew: BarChartView!
var days: [String]!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    days = ["Monday","Tuesday","life"]
    let task = [1.0,4.0,3.0]
    setChart(dataPoints: days, values: task)
}

func setChart(dataPoints : [String], values : [Double]){
    lineChartVIew.noDataText = "Nothining to display"

    var dataEntries : [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    var counter = 0.0

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        counter += 1
        let dataEntery = BarChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: counter)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntery)
    }

    let ChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Time")
    let chartData = BarChartData()
    lineChartVIew.data = chartData
    ChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()

    lineChartVIew.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)
}}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like a problem with the Charts framework which is not related to the Cocoapods dependency manager

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @SamBurns You tagged your question with CocoaPods (and it's in your question title too), but we think that your issue is because of a misuse or error in Charts, not related to CocoaPods which was just a tool to import Charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one it's is Working (Swift 4 Code).**

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var lineChartView: BarChartView!

var days: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday"]
         let task = [1.0,4.0,3.0,5.0]
         setChart(dataPoints: days, values: task)     
    }

    func setChart(dataPoints : [String], values : [Double]){

       lineChartView.noDataText = "Nothining to display"
       var dataEntries : [BarChartDataEntry] = []
       var counter = 0.0

       for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            counter += 1
            let dataEntery = BarChartDataEntry(x: counter, y:values[i], data: days as AnyObject)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntery)
       }

       let ChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Time")
       let chartData = BarChartData()
       chartData.addDataSet(ChartDataSet)
       lineChartView.data = chartData
       ChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
       lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)

   }
}
```

**Output is :**

[image]

**Modify Graph Hide and Show Axis and Labels**

```
lineChartView.leftAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false // Hide Left Axis Label
lineChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false // Hide Right Axis Label
lineChartView.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false // Hide Top Axis Label

lineChartView.leftAxis.enabled = false // Hide Left Axis Lines
lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false // Hide Right Axis Lines      
lineChartView.xAxis.enabled = false // Hide Right Axis Lines

lineChartView.legend.enabled = false //Hide Legend of Chart

lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "" // Hide or Change Chart Description text
```

Comment: You answer worked. I am having trouble with the x axis I dont want any text to be on there. Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: @SamBurns You can check the answer, I have done update it.

Comment: That worked. What about the Description Label at the bottom right of the graph.

Comment: @SamBurns You can check the Updated answer for Change Description Label text.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help. How would you get the name of the days that correspond with the weight on the bar. Right now the weight is on the top of the bars. I would like the day to be on the bottom of the bars. Thank you so much for your help so.

Comment: @SamBurns If this solution is worked for you then don't forgot  to upvote it .. happy to help :)