# not able to show response data on charts

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart, swiftcharts

i am getting json response and i want  to siaplay thatresponse as chart an useg SwiftCharts library for that but i am not able to show on chart let me show my response

**Response**

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 3
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        }
    ],
    "like_data": [
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 6
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        }
    ],
    "cmnt_data": [
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 1
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

and now i show u my code which i done for show on chart

**Code**

```
  let data = response.result
                if let dict = data.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
                    if let categorylist = dict["data"]{
                        self.searchlist = categorylist as! [AnyObject]
                        let task = [1.0,4.0,3.0,5.0]
                        self.setChart(dataPoints: self.searchlist as! [String], values: task)
                    }
                }

 func setChart(dataPoints : [String], values : [Double]){

        chartView.noDataText = "Nothining to display"
        var dataEntries : [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        var counter = 0.0

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            counter += 1
            let dataEntery = BarChartDataEntry(x: counter, y:values[i], data: days as AnyObject)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntery)
        }

        let ChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Time")
        let chartData = BarChartData()
        chartData.addDataSet(ChartDataSet)
        chartView.data = chartData
        ChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
        chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0)

    }
```

please check this updated code i am getting crash while i am adding my response data in my another searchList array a i not understand why i am getting crash

Comment: **Try This one it's Working it is a bug of Library** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612972/10150796

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani please check my updated code in my question i m getting crash

Comment: You missed **days** to replace with your input data set. please check it.

Comment: means noth able to understand

Comment: First of all, you check with the same data which I have used in an answer and check Chart is Display or not in your project after that do it with your Dataset.

Comment: Any `!` can crash the code. For example why is `searchlist` first force downcasted to `[AnyObject]` and then to `[String]`? By the way a JSON response in Swift 3+ is always `Any`, never `AnyObject`.

Comment: @Vishal Are you Getting Chart with same as my dataset code in your project?

Comment: Yes i am getting static data chart but when i am implemt my api response that i haveing issue

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani please give me solution for this

Comment: @Vishal You need to make String Array from your response data to pass data to chart dataset.

Comment: @Vishal Here self.searchlist as! [String] always Returns nil that's why crashed the App.

Comment: var searchlist: [String]! you mean like this?

Comment: Yes but if i declare String array then its force fully give me this self.searchlist as! [String]

Comment: @Vishal Loop the dict["data"] and Append each value into searchlist: [String]! and this searchlist pass to the Chart.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani then how can i fill my searchlist array with response data please help me

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani pelase give me simple example i am new to swift so not able to understand

Comment: @Vishal I will back after some time

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani ok no problem but please explain me with example that whats the problem

Comment: @Vishal Please Check your Question, I have done updated answer on it.