# How to use String values for X-Axis in Charts instead of doubles?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I want to display String values for X-Axis in line chart via using '[Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)'
I've followed tutorial for same [here](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/). As per wrote there 
 `let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)`
 I'm not finding in current latest version of library.
In, current library version's demo code I'm only able to fill `double` type of data for X-axis and Y-axis.
Please help me to solve this.
Here is desired output.
[image: Line chart]

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612972/10150796

Comment: That is available for barChart, but I want to draw line chart. So constructor is different.

Comment: It's not good to use String as X & Y values. You have to convert the string to double and use it.

Comment: @Satyam, I want to display "Jan", "Feb", "Mar" on X-axis as displayed in image.

Comment: @MrugeshTank You can do the same thing for any type of chart.

Comment: I used it long time back. There's a protocol IAxisValueFormatter that you can implement and achieve your result.

Comment: @Satyam, You saved my day. You can post this and some example as answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a protocol IAxisValueFormatter that you can implement and achieve your expected result.

**EDIT:**

How to use it

While initialising 
`chartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self`

and implementing protocol.

```
extension LineChart1ViewController: IAxisValueFormatter {
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        let months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","Auguest","September","October","November","December"]
        return months[Int(value)]
    }
}
```